# Getting warning message

Tags: warnings

I am trying to run this code:

```
 x = 0
 y = 0

newdata <- subset(data, subject_ids == 25773861)

for(i in newdata$classification_id){
   if(newdata$value == "Yes"){
     x = x + 1
   } else {
     y = y + 1 
   }
}
```

But keep getting this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (newdata$value_simple == 0) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (newdata$value_simple == 0) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any advice or help in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

The general code of

```
if(condition){
  some code
}else{
  some code}
```

only look at the first value in the vector. So it is basically warning you that it is only looking at the first value in the object newdata$value. I am assuming you are getting all in either x or y not a split like you would want.

The two things I would fix in that code, start at the first two lines of the for loop

```
x = 0
 y = 0

newdata <- subset(data, subject_ids == 25773861)

for(i in seq_along(newdata$classification_id)){ #seq_along makes a vector 1 to the length of your vector
   if(newdata$value[[i]] == "Yes"){ #This will subset the newdata$Value into single values
     x = x + 1
   } else {
     y = y + 1 
   }
}
```

Another option is to use the tidyverse, assuming you have it installed

```
library(tidyverse)
 data %>%
       filter(subject_ids == 25773861) %>%
       group_by(value) %>%
       count()
```